# How to share received data from socket in fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I open a **Bluetooth** socket in my main activity and receive information from other device.

As i show in image below i have two fragment in my activity.

[image]

How can i use information which receive from socket **Bluetooth** in both fragments .
note : fragment can change and in general i searching for proper way to share received data. I receive data with handler as below:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                connectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                        + connectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        msg.getData().getString(BluetoothChatService.MessageConstants.TOAST),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

Comment: i found EventBus library useful for my problem . github link is : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
but actually using mvvm architecture is best way if you are at start point of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use offline Databases such as Room . ( do not forget to execute your queries in the background thread. use executors and thread-pools). in addition to this, you also can use intents to transfer data between some fragments. finally, I think the best way to share data between fragments(or generally, modules) is to use an architecture having a shared repository such as MVVM, MVC etc. they both use offline DB as repositories.